# Array_unique can't be used

Tags: php, arrays, json, duplicates

I get json data from a api and i try to remove all duplicate element (if 2 element was named "aa" i want to remove one of both)
For that i do that

```
$plugins = Http::accept('application/json')->get('https://poggit.pmmp.io/plugins.min.json')->object();
$plugins = array_unique($plugins);
```

But i get

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.

When i `gettype` on `$plugins` i get `array`.

I was try with

```
        $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://poggit.pmmp.io/plugins.min.json'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Accept: */*'; // you can try to change with application/json
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
   $plugins = json_decode($result, true); // decode to array
   $plugins = array_unique($plugins);
```

But here i have array to string conversion at '$plugins = array_unique($plugins);'

Why do I have this error?

Comment: Should it be `)->get(`

Comment: Please share more details, like sample input data that could help to understand the problem. Obviously, an array can not be used as an input for `array_unique`

Comment: Does your object implements toArray()? so you can convert it to an array and you will be able to use array_unique

Comment: Input data are in my message i get it from 'https://poggit.pmmp.io/plugins.min.json'

Comment: "Input data are in my message" - no, it's not. As nobody knows what that `object()` method returns, it's pretty difficult to reproduce the problem

Comment: @Debuqer i say plugins are already of type array

Comment: If  `$plugins` was of type array, the given code would not throw the given error message

Comment: can you please share the result of $plugins. var_dump($plugins)

Comment: @Debuqer just go here for see content of plugin var https://poggit.pmmp.io/releases.min.json

Comment: @Bagou450 _Remove one of both_ So which one? First or second occurrence?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SORT_REGULAR` flag to compare the elements as they are, but be aware that arrays are only considered equal if they have the same key-value pairs:

```
$plugins = array_unique($plugins, SORT_REGULAR);
```

From the docs:

> Note: Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2 i.e. when the string representation is the same, the first element will be used.

Reference: https://www.php.net/array_unique

Answer (score 0):

So i try use your url to make a `GET` request using `cURL` in php, here my try:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://poggit.pmmp.io/plugins.min.json'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: */*'; // you can try to change with application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
   echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
$plugins = json_decode($result, true); // decode to array
$plugins = array_unique($plugins); // make it unique
print_r($plugins); // It's work!
```

Comment: array to string conversion at        $plugins = array_unique($plugins);

Answer (score -2):

Do you have try convert `stdClass` to to `Array` using `json_decode($plugins, true);` before using `array_unique($plugins)`.

Comment: when i do that i have json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, array given

i try to add json encode before decode and std class error on array unique

Comment: If `$plugins` would be an object, `json_decode` would not work, as its first argument must be a string